# Arguing that the time derivative of $\exp(-iHt)$ is $-iH\exp(-iHt)$ without taylor expansion

Tags: quantum-mechanics, operators, hilbert-space, time, differentiation

I would like to argue that the time derivative of $\exp(-iHt)$ is $-iH\exp(-iHt)$ without taylor expansion. $H$ is the hamiltonian and it is hermitian. Thus it can be diagonalized. But I cannot see how I can ignore the eigenvectors as if they do not exist and use chain rule, when I attempt to bring down the $H$ from the exponential.

Comment: What is your definition of exponential of an operator?

Comment: @yoric I take exponential of every matrix element.

Comment: If you do not *define* the [matrix exponential](https://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Matrix_exponential) through the Taylor expansion, as customary in the mainstream, you may still define it through the large *N* limit  of $(1\!\!1  -itH/N)^N$, and derive this, as you did in high-school calculus, no?

Comment: Would [math.SE] be a better home for this question?

Answer (score 0):

I'm not sure about your question but I'll try to clarify you a little bit about function of operators. Since they can be undestood as matrices, note that it's impossible to define something like $\exp(A)$. What one can do with operators is just multiply them. Hence, when one writes down a function of an operator $f(A)$ is indeed talking about the taylor serie of this function which will be:

$\sum_{n} C_n A^n$

where $A^n$ is an operation that takes matematically sense. Therefore, you cannot treat this kind of functions as usually functions and in order to omit any confusion, think always in terms of Taylor series.

Answer (score 0):

Exponential of a matrix is defined as Taylor expansion e.g.

https://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Matrix_exponential

So, it is hard not to use Taylor expansion due to the definition.